# How can i prevent webpack from adding source code in the sourcemap?

Tags: webpack, source-maps

How can i prevent webpack from adding source code in the sourcemap? I would like to be able to use a browser (for eg chrome) to specify the location of source files and souremap should just contain mapping from compiled code to source code.

Comment: Are you using `inline-source-map`? Try using just `source-map`

Comment: i am using just source-map. devtool: 'source-map', I would like to keep sourcemap in production but not the source code.